# UIDatePicker NSInternalInconsistencyException: unexpected number of calendar units error

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, crashlytics, uidatepicker

I got this crash report from Crashlytic that said error in UIDatePicker. Is it bug in iOS? Because seems like the entry point that touch my application only in the AppDelegate.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
unexpected number of calendar units: 4 for format: EEE ├'day': d┤ HH.mm (expecting at least 5 elements)
```

The full error stack:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x184bb5d04 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x183e04528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x184bb5bd8 +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x185545c24 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          0x18eab9b38 -[_UIDatePickerMode_DateAndTime elements]
5  UIKit                          0x18eab3898 -[_UIDatePickerMode displayedCalendarUnits]
6  UIKit                          0x18eab98f8 -[_UIDatePickerMode_DateAndTime displayedCalendarUnits]
7  UIKit                          0x18eaa8448 -[_UIDatePickerView _setMode:]
8  UIKit                          0x18eaa8694 -[_UIDatePickerView setDatePickerMode:]
9  UIKit                          0x18e55ac68 -[UIDatePicker initWithCoder:]
10 UIKit                          0x18e727160 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
11 UIKit                          0x18e726e98 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
12 UIKit                          0x18e57c0cc -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
13 UIKit                          0x18e727160 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
14 UIKit                          0x18e7272d8 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
15 UIKit                          0x18e726e98 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
16 UIKit                          0x18e57b40c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
17 UIKit                          0x18e35b17c -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:]
18 UIKit                          0x18e10aee4 -[UIViewController loadView]
19 UIKit                          0x18dfecba4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired]
20 UIKit                          0x18dfecad4 -[UIViewController view]
21 UIKit                          0x18e171680 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
22 UIKit                          0x18e0932c8 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:]
23 UIKit                          0x18e092f0c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews]
24 UIKit                          0x18e092e0c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]
25 UIKit                          0x1a3a651b8 -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews]
26 UIKit                          0x18dfea2f8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
27 QuartzCore                     0x188ba3ec8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
28 QuartzCore                     0x188ba7fa8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
29 QuartzCore                     0x188b16a98 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
30 QuartzCore                     0x188b3ceb4 CA::Transaction::commit()
31 QuartzCore                     0x188b3dcf4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
32 CoreFoundation                 0x184b5d848 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
33 CoreFoundation                 0x184b5b200 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
34 CoreFoundation                 0x184b5b7bc __CFRunLoopRun
35 CoreFoundation                 0x184a7bfb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
36 GraphicsServices               0x186913f84 GSEventRunModal
37 UIKit                          0x18e0502e8 UIApplicationMain
38 AwesomeApp                     0x100da4924 main (AppDelegate.swift:18)
39 libdyld.dylib                  0x18459e56c start
```

Comment: Please show your `set DateFormat style` code

Comment: @QuocNguyen the thing is, I don't which part of the codes generate this crash

Comment: in my case, this code generates this crash:
let picker = UIDatePicker()
picker.datePickerMode = .date

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a bug for `UIDatePicker` since iOS 11. It happens when device in certain setting for region and calendar. One of the scenario I can reproduce is:

- Region: Indonesia
- Calendar: Buddist

One way to fix this is by specifically set calendar to your intended format.

```swift
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.calendar = .gregorian
```

For an easy access in all usage of `UIDatePicker`. You may create an extension like so:

```swift
extension UIDatePicker {
  static func makeDatePicker(mode: UIDatePicker.Mode, maximumDate: Date? = nil) -> UIDatePicker {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.calendar = .gregorian
    datePicker.datePickerMode = mode
    datePicker.maximumDate = maximumDate
    return datePicker
  }
}
```

Also dont forget to bring this also to your `DateFormatter`. When `DateFormatter` initiated, it will use device default calendar. This is achievable with:

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
dateFormatter.calendar = .gregorian
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Comment: Interesting finding. I'll try out our solution.